# Why can't I clone a private repository via GIT?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

[image]

I added SSH key already successfully in GitHub.
I have no idea why I kept getting this error when tried to clone a private repo.

## SSH

```
➜  test git clone git@github.com:nike/consumer.git
Cloning into 'consumer'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

## HTTPS

```
➜  test git clone https://github.com/nike/consumer.git
Cloning into 'consumer'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/nike/consumer.git/' not found
```

## GitHub Desktop

success clone, fetch, commit and push
[image]

Why ? Did I miss anything else ?

---

## Connection confirmed

```
➜  test ssh -T git@github.com
Hi ${myname}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: The SSH key only applies to `ssh`, and won't let you access the repository via HTTPS. Have you confirmed that you can connect via `ssh`? See https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection.

Comment: Good idea, let me test that.

Comment: I got this `Hi myname! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Comment: Are you sure you're cloning the right url?  Do you have access to it through the github website?

Comment: Yes, I have access to it from the website, and I copied and pasted the actual URL from the cloning section only, please see : https://i.imgur.com/XsdtqJB.png

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am running into a similar issue

Comment: You are trying to download a repository from a organization. Have you tried to make a repository on your account and download it? If it succeeds, it is possible, that your organization have some sick policies and you should contact your DevOps team.

Comment: This could also be the issue that you have multiple git accounts configured on your windows/mac so when you clone the repo you should put your username before Github i.e `https://usernamehere@github.com/vi3global/consumer-engagement` if that does not works then I'm pretty sure that you only have special read access.

Answer (score 5):

> Yes, I have access to it from the website, and I copied and pasted the actual URL from the cloning section only

[image: URL]

Then the URL to clone would be

```
git@github.com:vi3global/consumer-engagement
# or
https://github.com/vi3global/consumer-engagement
```

Assuming that your account was added as a collaborator, since it is a private repository.

The URL would *not* be `git@github.com:*nike*`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm not sure why OP uses 'nike' to clone when clearly that's not his username, and the wrong repo name as well.

Comment: I used nike as an example as an example only that why I blur it out.

Comment: @code-8 so did you used `vi3global/consumer-engagement`? (the actual remote repository name)

Comment: Yes. I am using it right now and I can push. Commit and everything to it. Via GitHub desktop app signed in to my GitHub account of my company.

Comment: @code-8 OK. What does `git config --global credential.helper` return?

Comment: Sorry late reply, I ran that and see nothing as a response from the CLI;

Comment: @code-8 Then try, for an HTTPS URL, to register your GitHub PAT (personnal Access Token), after having set up a credential helper to cache said credential: `git config --global credential.helper manager-core` (check first if you see `git-credential-manager` or `git-credential-manager-core` in your local Git installation, under `/path/to/git/mingw64/libexec/git-core`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent a few hours debugging this. I don't know the specific reason as to why this works but I ended up restarting the SSH service:

```
System Preferences -> Sharing. 

Check and Un-check the Remote Login service.
```

This restarts the SSH agent and i was able to successfully clone the private repo with a custom ssh configuration.

Comment: I tried that and still see this : 

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'git@github.com:nike/consumer.git/' not found


Some how it kept appending the last `/` there even if I don't do it.

Comment: ```Cloning into 'consumer'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.```

This is usually what you get as the error message

Comment: Can you try running `brew upgrade git` on your mac. The latest version is 2.35.1 @code-8

Comment: Okay, I will try that, maybe it help;

Comment: Does GIT auto come with Mac, when we bought it.

Comment: Error: git not installed...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Had just created my own private repo on GH. Couldn't clone using the URL provided for ssh. I even created a new pair of SSH keys for the repo and added the pub file to the Deployed Keys for the repo. And added the key to my running ssh-agent.

In the end, the solution for me was to have my ssh-agent drop all the keys it knew about, `ssh-add -D`, and then add just the one key I wanted to use for the clone.

The first time I just added my newly created key for the repo. That worked. Then I removed the deploy key from the repo and dropped all ssh-agent keys again and this time added my GH account access key
and a `git clone` of the repo worked again. So I didn't need a unique key for each private repo.

So I think the GH clone protocol doesn't cycle through all keys that ssh-agent is holding. Setup it up with just the one, you can check with `ssh-add -l`.

A side note: Once I have the repo cloned the first time, I tend to add this to the .git/config [core] section so I don't need to mess with the ssh-agent for the repo on that machine again.

`sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github_account_key"`